# How to manage large 2D FFTs in cuda

Tags: image-processing, cuda, fft

I have succesfully written some CUDA FFT code that does a 2D convolution of an image, as well as some other calculations.

How do I go about figuring out what the largest FFT's I can run are? It seems to be that a plan for a 2D R2C convolution takes 2x the image size, and another 2x the image size for the C2R. This seems like a lot of overhead!

Also, it seems like most of the benchmarks and such are for relatively small FFTs..why is this? It seems like for large images, I am going to quickly run out of memory. How is this typically handled? Can you perform an FFT convolution on a tile of an image and combine those results, and expect it to be the same as if I had run a 2D FFT on the entire image?

Thanks for answering these questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CUFFT plans a different algorithm depending on your image size. If you can't fit in shared memory and are not a power of 2 then CUFFT plans an out-of-place transform while smaller images with the right size will be more amenable to the software.

If you're set on FFTing the whole image and need to see what your GPU can handle my best answer would be to guess and check with different image sizes as the CUFFT planning is complicated.

See the documentation : http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1_1/CUFFT_Library_1.1.pdf

I agree with Mark and say that tiling the image is the way to go for convolution. Since convolution amounts to just computing many independent integrals you can simply decompose the domain into its constituent parts, compute those independently, and stitch them back together. The FFT convolution trick simply reduces the complexity of the integrals you need to compute.

I expect that your GPU code should outperform matlab by a large factor in all situations unless you do something weird.

Answer (score 1):

It's not usually practical to run FFT on an entire image. Not only does it take a lot of memory, but the image must be a power of 2 in width and height which places an unreasonable constraint on your input.

Cutting the image into tiles is perfectly reasonable. The size of the tiles will determine the frequency resolution you're able to achieve. You may want to overlap the tiles as well.

Comment: The power of 2 issue is only if it is to run 100% optimally right? I have been running on image sizes that are variable and seem to be running faster than the matlab version of this same algorithm which is running on a 16 core box

Comment: @Derek, apparently there are FFT algorithms that do not impose that restriction. It's been a very long time since I looked at this stuff. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fft

Comment: Yah- I guess my main question has to do with the large FFTs that do not fit in on the GPU, and how to handle breaking the problem up